# Replicate the_date function when using a custom field

Tags: date-time

I used to use the published date to sort posts on my page. Now I am sorting the posts with a custom date/time field.

When using the published date I used the_date function, which only shows the date once if two posts are on the same day. For example:

```
March 14 
Headline for Post 1 
Headline for Post 2 (second post on the same day)

March 13
Headline for post 3 (only one post on this day)

March 12
Headline for post 4
Headline for post 5 (second post on same day)
```

However, when I use the custom date the date displays above each post. How can I make the custom date field not show when two posts have the same day? Thanks.

Comment: Had you looked at [`the_date()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_date/) source? It's rather short and simple to implement to skip same days.

Comment: It looks promising, but how to use with a custom field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_query` with is very usefull. In this snipet we get a week most viewed posts.

```
<?php 
                                        $args = array(
                                            'date_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'year' => date('Y'),
                                                    'week' => date('W'),
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                           'post_type'    => 'post',
                                           'post_status'  => 'publish',
                                           'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                                           'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                           'order' => 'DESC',
                                           'showposts' => '5'
                                        );
                                        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                                        ?>
```

Here is more examples for use a `date_query` argument. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-date-query/

Comment: Does date_query work with custom fields?

Comment: As you can see, there is a `meta_key`. Yes, it works. But you need check the custom field meta key id not name, if you use a ACF. Field key name is like a fied_3433232 for example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It looks like this method can show selections of posts, but will it replicate the_dates behavior of skipping the date on posts that are on the same day?

Comment: This won't work if the date is in a custom meta field as `the_date` depends on `globals` set up by [`setup_postdata()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3943)